# File exists but will not UNLINK (PHP)

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to check if a file exists and if so delete it.  For some strange reason, checking the file returns true but it won't unlink for the life of me.  Here is the code I have.

```
if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/uploads/'.$_POST['image_name'])) {
        if (@unlink(TEMPLATEPATH.'/uploads/'.$_POST['image_name'])) {
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";   
        }
    } else {
        echo "false";   
    }
```

*note --- without @ there is no errors...
*note2 --- this is on localhost windows w/wamp stack and before you say that's why it doesn't work, i confirmed that another site using same syntax works for them without any special permissions.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also for some strange reason people do not post errors... Oh, wait... You're suppressing the error by using @. Remove it, you will be enlightened.

Comment: In general it is a good rule of thumb NOT to use the @ error suppressor at all!

Comment: No I tried it with and without @...same thing

Comment: There is a note on the unlink manual page on php.net, about unlink working fine on one windows server in a production environment, and not working once they tried the script on their home computer.  They found that the file was open for some reason, and they couldn't unlink it because of that.  Perhaps it could be that your Antivirus is one of those that opens and checks files for viruses as they have access requested to them (real-time protection), like Microsoft Security Essentials, thus blocking the unlink.  Adding the web root or whatever to the AV's exception list might help.

Comment: @Phoenix - thanks for the advise however I am on lamp stack.  And another wordpress theme using same syntax  as i am and it works on their theme.  That is why i am totally confused.

Comment: It's not LAMP if it's on Windows by the way, the L stands for Linux, on Windows it's WAMP.

Comment: Ok if you want to be techinical...its a wamp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I am a dumbass and found out that the posted variable name has changed and should have been 'image' instead of 'image_name'....

Sorry for wasting you guys' time!

Answer (score 11):

Even if the file exists, it doesn't mean you have the permissions to delete it.

You should [**remove the `@` operator**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), which is silencing a potential error -- which is probably quite interesting.

And if you don't want error messages to be displayed to the user, you should :

- De-activate the displaying of error messages, with [**`display_errors`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)
- And log those errors to a file, for your own eyes, with [**`log_errors`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [**`error_log`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)

Comment: Ah you beat me to the edit suggesting to remove the @ to get any hidden errors out :) You're answer's the one!

Comment: I updated the question -- without @ doesn't make difference and not getting any message from it...

Comment: In this case, make sure that error_reporting is configured to report warnings and errors ; you can use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script -- and that those are either logged or displayed (you can use `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the beginning of your script).

Comment: @Rick: You should be getting some sort of error message. Are you sure you have your error reporting at an appropriate level? For development, try this: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` If the file doesn't delete, and that error reporting doesn't give you a message, then something is *seriously* messed up.

Comment: not sure if that would work as this is an AJAX call...but i've used is_writable function and it came back true. and file_exists comes back true...so I am stumped to why it won't unlink.

Comment: *(If I remember correctly)* In order to delete a file, you don't need write permission on that file itself ; instead, you need write permission of the directory which contains the file.

Comment: that would be weird as the same app created that folder..so if it can create it, it should be able to delete files within it...It takes ownership when it creates it. And it can put files in no problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Rick: If you take out the warning-suppressing `@`, does PHP return an access denied error message? If so, that's the problem. Try

```
if (file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/uploads/' . $_POST['image_name'])) {
   chmod(TEMPLATEPATH.'/uploads/'.$_POST['image_name']), 0755);

   if (unlink(TEMPLATEPATH . '/uploads/' . $_POST['image_name'])) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";   
    }
} else {
    echo "false";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others are saying, you need to have proper permissions to delete. Specifically, you need write permission. Try this:

```
$filename = TEMPLATEPATH.'/uploads/'.$_POST['image_name'];
if(is_writable($filename)) {
  unlink($filename)
} else {
  // error handling. You can check which condition is failing here
}
```

Comment: I used is_writable and came back true.

Comment: You only need `if(is_writable($filename))` `is_writable()` and `is_readable()` both have implied `file_exists()` as they return false if the file doesn't exist or is not writable/readable (depending on which function is used), and all three also do an Warning level notification on failure.

Comment: @Phoenix: You're absolutely right. I got confused because someone once told me to do that check, but thinking about it now, they were talking about `is_file` rather than `file_exists` since `file_exists` also applies to directories. I just got it a bit backwards here. Thanks.